# Unable to open the dial pad in asp.net mvc Mobile application using JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I was working on a contact list mobile application using asp.net MVC an JQuery Mobile. I have a phone number link like: 1234567890. I want to make a phone call when the user presses the link.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make the phone number a link using the `tel` protocol (much the same as you would do with an email address and `mailto`):

```
<a href="tel:1234567890">(123) 456-7890</a>
```

Comment: I have already tried that and it is showing me error message.

Comment: It says "The webpage at tel:1234567890 might be temporarily down or ... Also <a href="mailto:yasnake@gmail.com">yasnake@gmail.com</a> has the same issue. It is not opening the mail application when I tap on the email link. I tested both on google emulator and the phone link is opening skype and the email link is opening outlook as expected. But after I download the app and install on my galaxy s5, it is showing me error on both cases. Thanks for your time. Do I need to include something in the application.

Comment: What browser are you using on your phone? Is it Chrome for Android?